# WordPress Can't get all the posts which respects tags and categories conditions

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I've created a custom type of post, and I want to get all the posts which are in a category and a tag. Unfortunately I don't know why it returns only one post (I should have at least 3 or 4)

> this is my code :

```
$tag = $_GET["tag"];
$cat = $_GET["cat"];

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post_product',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'numberposts' => -1,
    array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'cating'
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'tagging')
    )
);

$custom_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $custom_query->have_posts() ):

    while ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) :
        $custom_query->the_post();

        $product_terms = wp_get_object_terms(get_the_ID(), 'cating');
        $product_terms_tag = wp_get_object_terms(get_the_ID(), 'tagging');

        if(!empty($product_terms) && !empty($product_terms_tag)){
            if(!is_wp_error( $product_terms ) && !is_wp_error( $product_terms_tag )){

                foreach($product_terms as $term){
                    if(strcmp($term->name, $cat) == 0) {

                        foreach($product_terms_tag as $term_tag){
                            if(strcmp($term_tag->name, $tag) == 0) {

                                // display here

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone have an idea why do I get only one post or nothing since they are posts which respects thos conditions.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your [Taxonomy Query parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) are not well formed. And you are not using any of your `$_GET` variables either.

Assuming you're getting the term ID through the `$_GET`, It should be something like:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post_product',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
         array(
            'taxonomy' => 'tagging',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => (int) $tag
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'cating',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => (int) $cat
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I actually get the term name. I was using my get variables in tests `strcmp($term->name, $cat) == 0`, so my idea was to retrieve all the posts through the loop and display them according to the conditions. I have tried your code and removed the conditions and the result doesn't respect the `$cat` value..

Comment: You can also use the `slug` instead of the `id` in the `field` parameter.

Comment: You should also use `posts_per_page` instead of `numberposts`.

Answer (score 0):

Add $post_count to your $args array with the number of posts you want